# В мобильном приложении не переводено описание причины "Не по теме, потому что..."

Tags: дефект, локализация, причины-закрытия, мобильное-приложение

В приложении нет перевода описания.

[image]

В мобильной и нормальной версиях сайта все ок.

Comment: В приложении или мобильной версии?

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica в приложении для ифона. В мобильной версии все ок.

Comment: Приложения не развивается. Все тикеты по поводу него игнорируются =/

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica да это, увы, известно :( Но переводы были нормальные, потом пропали, как и на сайте, а теперь в трех местах есть, а в двух нет. Видимо это не в самом приложении, а где-то с сайта берется.

Comment: Мало того, приложения для старых версий ios отличаются, переводами, багами и они не исправляются уже давно.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Да там приложение одно и тоже, но с каждой новой иОС добавляются баги. Приложение все то же, а багов все больше. Андроидное тоже с 2017 года уже не обновлялось, не знаю, как там с багами.

Comment: @Эникейщик и тем не менее я им пользуюсь